# adding vertical text each item in text file writeline with some text

Tags: vb.net

I am populating a listbox with some text & saving the output to textfile (sObj.txt)

```
'Saving items of lb1 in a file under C:\temp
    Dim i As Integer
    W = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
    For i = 0 To lb1.Items.Count - 1
        W.WriteLine(lb1.Items.Item(i))
    Next
    W.Close()
```

This text file contains 3 (for example) entries, let's say abc in 1st line, def in 2nd line & ghi in the 3rd line.

Now I want to append another text file (MPadd.txt) using sObj.txt entries such that I get something like the following:

```
'Appending listbox items to the file MPadd.txt

    Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
        SW.WriteLine("some text" & abc & "some text")
        SW.WriteLine("some text" & def & "some text")
        SW.WriteLine("some text" & ghi & "some text")
    End Using
```

Please help in getting it correctly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just read all the lines from the first file (just three lines so it is not a problem) and then loop over these lines adding prefix and postfix text as you like

**EDIT**
Following your last example

```
Dim commands() = 
{
    "cdhdef -t ftpv2 -c r -f {0} -x ",
    "cdhdsdef -v CPUSRG {0} ",
    "cacls K:\AES\data\Cdh\ftp\{0}\Archive /E /G OSSUSER:C"
} 

Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    ' Loop only for the number of strings in commands (max 3 now)
    for x = 0 to commands.Length - 1
        line = objeLines(x).Trim
        ' This check will prevent empty lines to be used for the output 
        If line <> string.Empty Then
            SW.WriteLine(string.Format(commands(counter), line))
            counter += 1
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

This example use [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) where you define a format string and a progressive placeholder where you want to insert another value.

Of course this will work only if you have just 3 lines in your input file

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I understand correctly your code will add the same "prefix text" & "postfix text" for each line found in the sObj.txt file. But the problem is that the "prefix text" & "postfix text" are not the same every time. For better understanding 
 
`code`

Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    for Each line on objLines
        SW.WriteLine("sometext1" & line & "sometext2")
        SW.WriteLine("sometext3" & line & "sometext4")
        SW.WriteLine("sometext5" & line & "sometext6")
    Next
End Using

Comment: So you have some text source that you need to merge with the original file? Please add the example of the other text to your original question

Comment: Or do you need to insert every line of the first file inside the corrispondent line of the second file?

Comment: Following is the example.

Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    for Each line on objLines
        SW.WriteLine("prefixtext1" & line & "postfixtext2")
        SW.WriteLine("prefixtext3" & line & "postfixtext4")
        SW.WriteLine("prefixtext5" & line & "postfixtext6")
    Next
End Using

Comment: But these text are fixed as you have typed? (For example, if you have a forth line you write 'prefixtext7' and 'postfixtext8')?

Comment: No these text is just for example. To clear here is the actual thing what I want:

Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    for Each line on objLines
        SW.WriteLine("cdhdef -t ftpv2 -c r -f " & abc & " -x " )
        SW.WriteLine("cdhdsdef -v CPUSRG " & def & " ")
        SW.WriteLine("cacls K:\AES\data\Cdh\ftp\" & ghi & "\Archive /E /G OSSUSER:C")
    Next
End Using

Comment: You see I'm just writing the prefix & postfix texts in each line & they are different in each line. What I want to acheve is to somehow get the items from sObj.txt to appear between the pre & postfix texts.

Comment: this code is not working...it's giving error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." Please help !!

Comment: How many lines are present in your file? Pay attention at the Last line, you shouldn't have the cursor on an empty final line

Comment: I have just reviewed this answer as usual and found an error in the starting point of the array (Counter value), array in NET start at index zero, so we  need to set the starting index accordingly, answer updated